# Namespace nesting in C++/CLI

Tags: visual-c++, namespaces, c++-cli, nested, managed-c++

I know nesting of namespaces is allowed in C++/CLI. So my question is if we have something like this:

```
...
namespace one
{
    // blah blah blah
    // ...

    namespace two
    {
        // another set of blah blah blah
        // ...
    }
}
```

and I need to use some functions and variables in ***namespace two***, do I use:

```
one::two
```

or

```
one.two
```

Another question is that if I have a statement like

```
using namespace one;
```

do I have access to variables and functions in any nested namespaces like

```
namespace two
```

I'm asking because, in some programs I have seen (and written), there's something like:

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Text;
using namespace System::IO;
```

Isn't the **System** namespace supposed to cover the **System::Text** and **System::IO** namespaces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use

```
one::two::some_variable_or_function
```

The `.` operator is for accessing non-static `struct`/`class` members. Static members can then again be accessed through the scope resolution operator `::`.

If you only would use `using System;`, you could access the `System::Text` functions/variables by

```
Text::some_function_or_variable
```

`using` the parent namespace does not imply importing all sub-namespaces.

Comment: More correctly the dot operator accesses instance members of classes, static members are also accessed by using `::`

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes, you need use `one::two` instead of `one.two` to access symbols in a nested namespace.
2. If you just using `namespace one;` you don't automatically have the access to the nested namespace. You'll have to use `two::`

Example:

```
namespace one
{
    int i;

    namespace two
    {
        int j;
    }
}
```

If you use:

```
using namespace one;
```

Your code looks like:

```
i = 1;
two::j = 2;
```

If you use:

```
using namespace one;
using namespace one::two;
```

Your code looks like:

```
i = 1; //Compile fails if no "using namespace one".
j = 2;
```

Comment: Thanks. Just found that out immediately I posted the question.

Answer (score 2):

In general, you use the dot only when you're referring to a member of an instance, and `::` everywhere else.  So to access stuff in your namespace `two`, you'd call it `one::two::whatever`.

As for `using namespace System;`, it'd import stuff from the `System` namespace.  While `System::IO` and `System::Text` are in `System`, it doesn't import them directly into the current namespace.  AFAIK you'd be able to say `using namespace System;` and then refer to a class within a nested namespace as, say, `IO::Stream`.  But that would get confusing fast, if you use a bunch of namespaces.

Answer (score 2):

> one::two
>
> or
>
> one.two

You need to use **one::two**. one.two is the syntax for *package* access in *Java*

> Another question is that if I have a
>   statement like
>
> using namespace one;
>
> do I have access to variables and
>   functions in any nested namespaces
>   like
>
> namespace two

**No**, you can use them as `two::` instead of `one::two::`

> I'm asking because, in some programs I
>   have seen (and written), there's
>   something like:
>
> using namespace System;
>   using namespace System::Text;
>   using namespace System::IO;
>
> Isn't the System namespace supposed to
>   cover the System::Text and System::IO
>   namespaces?

**No**, they aren't the same. You have to specify *usage* of each child namespace.

Answer (score 0):

1) one::two
2) `using` a parent namespace doesn't automatically expand any nested namespace.